# DDMathParser in .mm file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c++, ddmathparser

In my Xcode project I need to rename my ViewController.m in ViewController.mm 
, but I also need the DDMathParser.

I compile the parser in the .m file without any errors.
But when I compile it in the .mm file I get following errors:

Parse issue at line:

```
- (DDOperatorAssociativity) associativityForOperator:(NSString *)operator;

"expected identifier"
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention.  I've filed a bug (https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/issues/21) and will get around to fixing this at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chage the name of the parameter from `operator` to anything else. `operator` is a keyword in C++.